# Luxon Convert UTC iso time to specific timzone time in millisecond

Tags: javascript, datetime, luxon

I am using luxon to convert dates in millisecond as per timzone. I am receiving the time in ISO format but when I applies luxon to convert dates it does but when I am parsing it in millisecond I am getting no difference in millisecond with current and specified timzone.

```
console.log("== Local Zone == ");
console.log(DateTime.local().zoneName);
const sd = DateTime.fromISO("2019-07-27T07:37:49.211Z");
console.log(sd.toMillis());

console.log("== Updated Zone == ");
Settings.defaultZoneName = "America/Chicago";
console.log(DateTime.local().zoneName);
const hd = DateTime.fromISO("2019-07-27T07:37:49.211Z");
console.log(hd.toMillis());
```

Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the same value (`1564213069211`), because the input string (`"2019-07-27T07:37:49.211Z"`) ends with `Z` that stands for UTC offset.

So Luxon simply takes into account the UTC+0 offset and displays results accordingly.

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const Settings = luxon.Settings;
console.log("== Local Zone == ");
console.log(DateTime.local().zoneName);
const sd = DateTime.fromISO("2019-07-27T07:37:49.211Z");
console.log(sd.toMillis());
const sdNoZ = DateTime.fromISO("2019-07-27T07:37:49.211");
console.log(sdNoZ.toMillis());

console.log("== Updated Zone == ");
Settings.defaultZoneName = "America/Chicago";
console.log(DateTime.local().zoneName);
const hd = DateTime.fromISO("2019-07-27T07:37:49.211Z");
console.log(hd.toMillis());
const hdNoZ = DateTime.fromISO("2019-07-27T07:37:49.211");
console.log(hdNoZ.toMillis());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.25.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, do we need to remove z from the string to get the timezone specific date?

Comment: `"2019-07-27T07:37:49.211Z"` has the "full" info date, time + timezone and it represent a given instant of time (see Time Zone Converter [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20190727T073700&p1=1440&p2=64&p3=1038&p4=215)). Converting it to millis will always show `1564213069211`. Removing the Z will drop the timezone info, so it will represent a different instant of time according to the timezone taken into account.